# Using MsBuild in CMD without .sln or .csproj files

Tags: c#, asp.net, msbuild

I know how to use command prompt for executing MSBild.exe to build a project by referring to a .sln or .csproj file, for instance following code in CMD works fine and builds the project:

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe C:\Projects\MySolution.sln
```

What I'm about to know is how to build a project by just referring the project root, since I work with a WebSite and not a WebApplication, there is no .sln file mostly (although I can create one), is there any way to build a project by code like this:

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe C:\Projects\
```

missing MySolution.sln at the end of address?

Keep in mind that visual studio builds a Website while there is no .sln file around.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from instructions, you always need to put path with your `solution.sln` and the command would be like:

`msbuild [pathToProject]\[solutionName].sln /t:Build /p:Configuration=Release /p:TargetFramework=v4.6.1` (the version depends on which do you need.